# How do I use alt code symbols in c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio for C++ and when using `alt` symbols it returns a `?`. Why?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The encoding of the cpp file and the one of the console in which the output is shown are different.

Comment: @tni Why do you believe that this were a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ***Encoding what you need***);

Maybe not the best, but simple option to set console encoding output on what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You've not set any supported encoding for your program and it's commonly not used in console, that's why you're getting the error. Although, this's yet possible.

You may take the help of `fcntl.h` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"Hello, \u2663!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>**Note:** You may find out the complete list of Unicode character set in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).</sup>

It'll print the symbols correctly:

```
Hello, ♣!
```

As an image example:

[image: Builtin Unicode support]

Comment: If this answer solves your problem， I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.